# Why there is no "You've gained the privilege" when you pass 1000 reputation points?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just passed 1k reputation on askubuntu.com (hooray, carry on). When other reputation privilege milestones are passed (at least each time I can remember), there is nice "You've gained the privilege" message (bar in the top of the screen).

However, when 1k is passed, there is nothing (at least in superuser.com or in askubuntu.com). Why is that? Are "Create gallery chat rooms" and "view vote counts" so minor, there is no reason to inform users?

Answer (score 9):

The system takes into account if you're a "veteran" or not when deciding to notify about new privileges (I think "veterans" are people with 200 rep on another SE site, but I'm not certain). All the privileges before [editing](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/edit) do not notify veterans, since they're somewhat minor and it's assumed you already know about them anyway

Comment: Well, definitely limit is not 200 rep. However, "minor privileges" explanation sounds more plausible.

Comment: I didnot get a notification when i crossed 500 on superuser and this was a first so I am guessing 500 is when SE starts considerng a veteran